# Trouble with lookbehind and lookahead

Tags: python, regex

I'm having a hard time trying to get this simple RegEx to work. I need to capture the message "*Windows Event Logs Cleared*" or any other message that might be in that position.

```
text = """2023-04-05 / 15:53:58 104 Windows Event Logs Cleared 21 low SRVR3 - j.smith 1
          2023-03-20 / 15:17:55 4738 Account Configured with Never-Expiring Password 47 medium DC02SRV - m.rossi 2"""
pattern = '(?<=\d{3}|\d{4}|-)(.*?)(?=\s\d{2}\s)'
regex = re.findall(pattern,text,re.MULTILINE))'
```

Current output:

```
Windows Event Logs Cleared
```

Expected output:

```
Windows Event Logs Cleared
Account Configured with Never-Expiring Password
```

Note:

1. The date and time are always the same pattern
2. The message starts just before a 3-digit number or a 4-digit number (in these examples 104 and 4738), but it could also be a -
3. The message varies in length
4. The message always ends just before the 2-digit number, which in these examples are 21 for the first and 47 for the second.

If anyone knows of a good, concise, gobbledygook-free tutorial, please lemme know.

Comment: That's not valid Python code. Please add the quotes. In particular, the way you quote the regexp is important (you should use a raw string literal).

Comment: Does every line in the log have a date/time?  If so, then just `' '.join(line.split()[4:])` is a better way.  It's a string problem, not a regex problem.

Comment: You must be using PyPi regex, right? Or are you testing at regex101 with PCRE option checked?

Comment: @TimRoberts That won't stop at the number `21` after the message.

Comment: Try `m = re.search(r'^[\d\s:/-]*?\b\d{3}\s+(\S.*?)\s+\d{2}\b', text)` and then `if m: print(m.group(1))`

Comment: I don't understand your lookbehind `(?<=\d{3}|\d{4}|-)`. That matches either a 3-digit number, a 4-digit number, or `-`. So it's matching the `202` part of `2023-04-05`. If you want it to match the whole date, it should be `(?<=\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})`

Comment: You forgot to use a raw string for the regexp. That might not be a problem for this regexp, but it can cause problems with others. You should *always* use a raw string just in case.

Comment: @Barmar Yeah, because in the logs, the codes are 3 or 4 digits, but if there is no code, then it uses s -. So I thought I'd use the | for options/choices.

Comment: I assumed that part of the regexp was for the date. You need to add that to the lookbehind, otherwise it will match the first number, which is in the date.

Comment: @Barmar yes, but it's the lookbehind that's cramping my style. Know of any good tutorial on that?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Actually, it works only if there is a 3-digit number, but it doesnt capture it if it is a 4-digit number or a -

Comment: You have explained where the message starts, but not where it ends. Could you add that to your question?

Comment: @TimRoberts Yes, all the logs have the same pattern, except for the code (3 or 4 digits, or the - if there is no value). Then, all messages are followed by a 2-digit value.

Comment: Sorry, what's the question exactly? Recommendations are off-topic here, but probably a good place to start is the official Python [Regex how-to](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html). Apart from that, that code doesn't produce that output. Actually, it's syntactically invalid (errant `)'`), but if you fix that, then you get `re.error: look-behind requires fixed-width pattern`. Please make a [mre]. See [ask] for tips like how to write a good title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could look a bit further behind, starting at the last colon that is part of the timestamp.

If doing this with the `regex` module (instead of `re`), then variable width look behind is possible, but with `re` you can instead split into multiple alternative fixed-width look-behind assertions in this way:

```
(?:(?<=:\d\d \d{3} )|(?<=:\d\d \d{4} )|(?<=:\d\d - ))(.*?)(?=\s\d{2}\s)
```

If using `regex`, then you can even use `\K` instead of a look behind assertion:

```
:\d\d (?:\d{3,4}|-) \K(.*?)(?=\s\d{2}\s)
```

Answer (score 1):

With standard Python `re`, lookbehinds have to be a fixed length. Since the message can be preceded by a variable-length number, you can't use a lookbehind for this (the third-party `regex` library overcomes this restriction).

The workaround is to use a capture group for the message that you want to extract.

The other problem with your regexp is that it doesn't match the date and time before the message.

```
pattern = r'^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} / \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2} (?:-|\d{3,4}) (.*?) \d{2}'
```

When you use this, capture group 1 will contain the message.

Comment: Hey, not sure if you saw it, but I updated the question and examples. What I'm using now only gives me one message instead of the two provided. I tried your idea, but I get an empty list.

Comment: You need to use `flags=re.MULTILINE` so that `^` will match each line. Also, does the second line really have indentation before the the date? That seems unusual for a log file.